# Simplified effect of viscosity on flowrate when flowing from a cylinder through a small hole?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, viscosity

I'm writing a high school project and am studying the effect of viscosity on the flow rate when a Newtonian liquid (concentrated sugar with water) flows out of a hole (let's say of radius r << radius R of the cylindrical container) at the bottom of a cylindrical container.

While I'm aware of the Navier-Stokes equation, I can't fathom the concept (i.e. it's beyond high school physics). I tried to use Poissueilli's equation, but with no given dynamic pressure gradient, such an effect on the flow rate becomes difficult to determine.
I'm trying to derive a flow time vs. viscosity & r (with a given length, uniform density, etc.) and therefore another possible formula relating pressure gradient and known variables (length, volume, density, viscosity, flow rate, jet velocity, the velocity of the tank, etc) would be very helpful for me.

What concepts would be beneficial for my exploration? It's alright if it includes *some* calculus 2 content (as I've already taken the course), but partial derivatives are way beyond high school. Additionally, is there a way the Navier-Stokes equation be 'simplified' or should I consider another law/theorem?

Flow is assumed to be laminar with uniform density & viscosity at a constant temperature. R of the cylinder is approximately 0.3 cm, while r is approx. 0.1 cm. The height of the cylinder is approximately 1.5 m. The fluid is very viscous.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As a first approximation I'd suggest applying the Poiseuille equation with the pressure gradient taken to be the hydrostatic pressure $\rho g d$. I don't know how well this would work — my guess is not very well, but at least it's a place to start.

Comment: this resource: https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/148364855.pdf should be useful.

Comment: @Gert I'll be reviewing this source and I can see it has a lot of useful information in the document! Thanks.

Comment: @d_b Thanks for the info, I'll be checking it out